# Azure Data Factory - how to structure slices for erratically arriving blobs

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have blobs that do not arrive on a fixed schedule but the contents need to be loaded into an Azure SQL DB as timely as possible, and there is some lag on when they can arrive.

The blobs are now named with the following convention `logs/{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/{minute}/{second}`

How should a data factory be coded to load these files as soon as possible, and ideally not generate failures if a file is missing?

### What I have so far

#### Input data

```
    {
    "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Table.json",
    "name": "blobs",
     "properties": {
    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Minute",
      "interval": 15
    },
    "external": true,
    "linkedServiceName": "blob",
    "policy": { "externalData": { "dataDelay": "1:00:00" } },
    "structure": [
      {
        "name": "Column0",
        "type": "Int64"
      }
      ],
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "typeProperties": {
      "folderPath": "myblobs/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}",
      "format": {
        "type": "TextFormat",
        "rowDelimiter": "\n",
        "columnDelimiter": "\t"
      },
      "partitionedBy": [
        {
          "name": "Year",
          "value": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "date": "SliceStart",
            "format": "yyyy"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Month",
          "value": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "date": "SliceStart",
            "format": "%M"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Day",
          "value": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "date": "SliceStart",
            "format": "%d"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Hour",
          "value": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "date": "SliceStart",
            "format": "%H"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Minute",
          "value": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "date": "SliceStart",
            "format": "%m"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### Pipeline

```
{
    "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Pipeline.json",
    "name": "insert",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Insert data from blobs to sql db",
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "copyblobtosql",
                "type": "Copy",
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "blobs"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "tbl"
                    }
                ],
              "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                  "type": "BlobSource",
                  "recursive": false
                },
                "sink": {
                  "type": "SqlSink",
                  "writeBatchSize": 0,
                  "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                },
                "translator": {
                  "type": "TabularTranslator",
                  "columnMappings": "Column0:id"
                }
              },
                "policy": {
                    "concurrency": 10,
                    "executionPriorityOrder": "OldestFirst",
                    "retry": 3,
                    "timeout": "01:00:00"
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 15
                }
            }
        ],
        "start": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2099-05-05T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

#### Output data

```
{
    "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Table.json",
    "name": "tbl",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "linkedServiceName": "db",
        "structure": [
            {"name": "id","type": "Int32"}
          ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "tableName": "tbl"
        },
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 15
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the blobs arrive pretty often based on how you have the folder structure defined.  You can try using an azure function blob trigger https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-storage/ to kick off your ADF pipeline.  I have used an azure function to kick off an adf pipeline but not on that frequent of a schedule, so I am not 100% sure how it would behave.

Comment: Interesting idea! I'm guessing that's using the c# interface to adf? A language I'm rubbish at, but I found a potentially useful posts on a similar(ish) topic that turned out to be from your blog :)

Comment: Ha!  Yes the code in that post is using C# function.  You could use that same code in a blob trigger c# function the only thing you would need to do is get the blob folder path of the new entry and pull out the date and time to set as the pipeline start/end values.  I have also taken that example further by having the final step of a logic app trigger the azure function which then triggers the adf pipeline.  I will have another post about that soon.

Comment: In the end I just coded in the function - it was easier! Will leave open just in case things change